# mongo update to ignore some fields or upsert

Tags: c#, mongodb

I pass my model as a generic type to my repo, hence I know which fields to ignore on upsert. i.e if the document does exist ignore these fields, but if the document does not exist, insert the document.

Bu all example i see talk of updating the certain fields, e.g

```
var update = Builders<T>.Update.Set(m => m.IsDone, model.IsDone);
```

Now I want to insert `IsDone` only if the document doesn't exist. but when it does exists keep the value in db, and update other model fields.

```
class Repo<T> where T: BaseModel
{
}

class BaseModel
{ 
  string Id { get; set; }
  bool IsDone { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a shell code:

```
db.yourDb.update(
    <your_query>,
    {
        "$setOnInsert": { "IsDone": <is_done_value> },
        "$set": { "SomeField": "<some_field_value>" }
    },
    {
        upsert: true
    }
)
```

They key point is that for an existing document only `SomeField` is updated, but if no document matches the query a new document is inserted and both `IsDone` and `SomeField` are set. I believe you can convert this shell code to C# quite easily.

Comment: It's a generic type. I have access to only `Id` and `IsDone`. not  `SomeField`

Comment: I have used this field to show the idea. You can use "$setOnInsert" operator to achieve your goal - that's the key point. Look at this: http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_UpdateDefinitionBuilder_1_SetOnInsert__1_1.htm